# Varying line color by group in a faceted line graph with only one line in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

below is code to produce data and a ggplot2 faceted line plot, it seems to work fine. However, I'd like to change the color of the line based on the value of an additional (group), which is not currently in my example. I've tried adding:

```
+element_line(color=combined$group))
```

But It that did not change anything. Is what I am trying to do possible? Again, I want to keep only 1 line in each facet, but change the color based on the value of "group". Thanks in-advance for your help!

```
require(ggplot2)    
Year<-c(rep(2012,10),rep(2013,10),rep(2014,10))
MULTDV<-rnorm(30)
Construct<-factor(rep(1:10,3))
group<-rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),3)

combined<-as.data.frame(cbind(Year, MULTDV, Construct, group))
qplot(factor(Year), MULTDV, data=combined, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, stat="identity") + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="steelblue3", geom="line", aes(group=1))+facet_wrap(~Construct,  nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your code does not produce a "faceted line plot" and `FactTest` was not defined anywhere. However, the following code should get you close to what you're trying to do:

```
combined<-data.frame(Year, MULTDV, Construct, group)

qplot(factor(Year), MULTDV, data=combined, 
      geom = "line", group = Construct, color = factor(group),
      facets = ~ Construct)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended-up doing the following, which worked, though there is probably a more elegant way to do it.

```
require(ggplot2)    
Year<-c(rep(2012,10),rep(2013,10),rep(2014,10))
MULTDV<-rnorm(30)
Construct<-factor(rep(1:10,3))
group<-rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),3)
combined<-as.data.frame(cbind(Year, MULTDV, Construct, group))
cols<- c("1"="steelblue3","2"="red")

ggplot(combined,aes(x=factor(Year),y=MULTDV))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=2, colour=factor(group)))+
    facet_wrap(~Construct,  nrow = 2)+
    geom_point()+
    scale_colour_manual(values = cols, guide="none")+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

aaronwolen's code seemed to give me a similar result when I tried it, I'd just already figured out this other way before I saw his response. Thanks aaron!